# Let $W$ and $U$ be subspaces of a finite vectorspace V such that $W \subset U$ (so $W\neq U$). Show that $\dim(W) < \dim(U)$.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

It is trivial that $\dim(W) \le \dim(U)$, but I'm struggeling to show that $\dim(W) \neq \dim(U)$.

I'm thinking of a proof by contradiction like this:

$\dim(W)=\dim(V) \implies  W=V$

but I can't think of anything rigorous.

Comment: Are you presuming that $V$ is a finite dimensional space?

Comment: Yes, I corrected my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $\dim W=n$. Let $w_1,\ldots,w_n$ be a basis for $W$. Since $W\subset U$, then $w_1,\ldots,w_n$ is a linearly independent set in $U$. Thus,
$$n\leq\dim U.$$
Suppose that $n=\dim U$. Since $w_1,\ldots,w_n$ is a linearly independent set in $U$ and $\dim U=n$, then $w_1,\ldots,w_n$ is a basis for $U$. Thus, for any $u\in U$, we have
$$u=a_1w_1+\cdots+a_nw_n$$
for some $a_1,\ldots a_n\in\Bbb F$.

Since $w_1,\ldots,w_n\in W$, it follows that $u=a_1w_1+\cdots+a_nw_n\in W$ for all $u\in U$, which is a contradiction, because $W\subset U$. Thus, $n=\dim U$ is false. Therefore, $n<\dim U$ which means that
$$\dim W<\dim U.$$

Answer (score 1):

Let $W\subset U$ and $\mathcal B=\{w_1,...,w_n\}$ being a basis of $W$. If $\dim(W)=\dim(U)$ then $\mathcal B$ is also a basis of $U$, and thus $$W=\text{Span}(\mathcal B)=U,$$ which is a contradiction.

Comment: Why does the dimensions being equal necessarily mean that they share the same basis?

Answer (score 0):

We know that if $W$ and $U$ are two subspaces of a finite vector space such that $\dim(W)=\dim(U)$ and $W$ contained in $U$, then $W=U$.

And now we use simple logic
$p$ implies $q$,
not $q$ implies not $p$,
where $p$, $q$ any statement.
So,
$W$ is not equal to $U$ (given) implies $\dim(W)$ is not equal to $\dim(U)$.
Since we also given $W$ is contained in $U$,
then $\dim(W)$ less than $\dim(U).$

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).