# If $L$ is a proper subspace of $V$ ($V\ne L$), then $\dim L < \dim V$.

Tags: vector-spaces

I am trying to understand the proof of the following statement:

$V$ is a finite-dimensional vector space.

If $L$ is a proper subspace of $V$ ($V\ne L$), then $\dim L < \dim V$.

If $L$ is a proper subspace of a vector space $V$ $(L \neq V)$ and $b_1, \ldots, b_k$ is a basis for the subspace $L$, then $\text{span}(b_1, \ldots, b_k) \subsetneqq V$, and $b_1, \ldots, b_k$ can be extended to form a basis for the entire space $V$ (which includes at least one additional vector). From this, it follows that $\dim L < \dim V$.

Can someone explain to me why can't $\text{span}(b_1,\ldots,b_k)=V$? So it can only be a subset, cannot be equal to $V$. Why is that?

Comment: No sens in infinite dimension.

Comment: Because $b_1, \dots, b_k$ are linearly independent (as they're a basis for $L$). If their span gives $V$, then they're a basis for $V$.

Comment: @MathStudent, and how this contradicts anything?

Comment: @Piquito, fixed.

Comment: They can't be from $L$, as $L<V$ ($L\ne V$).

Comment: I have answered your question here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4841773/let-w-and-u-be-subspaces-of-a-finite-vectorspace-v-such-that-w-subset-u/4841791#4841791

Answer (score 2):

Since $L = \operatorname{span} \{b_1, \dots, b_k\}$ and we know that $L \neq V$ we can't have $\operatorname{span} \{b_1, \dots, b_k\} = V$.

Comment: Does this answer your question?

Comment: Why can't we have that? It is not clear from what we have as theorems...

Comment: If $L$ equals the span and the span also equals $V$, then $L = V$, contradicting the hypothesis that $L$ is a **proper** subspace of $V$.

Answer (score 0):

If what's written does not help you understand what's going on, let me try something else.

Suppose $\text{span}(b_1,\ldots,b_k)=V$. We will show that then $L=V$ which is what we don't want.

If $x\in L\Rightarrow x\in\text{span}(b_1, \ldots, b_k)=V\Rightarrow x\in V.$

If $x\in V=\text{span}(b_1,\ldots,b_k)=L\Rightarrow x\in L.$

So $L=V$.

We have something like this $$L=\text{span}(b_1,\ldots,b_k)=V$$